# How to split into sections the module admin panel?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I created a new payment module. The new payment method has two options and I need to separate them into two sections, as in the following image:

[image]

How to split into sections the module admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

This is added by PayPal module, functionality like that is not a part of "core" Magento (even tho the PayPal is there OOTB).

If you want to implement something like that, you may want to take a look at a file:

`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/system.xml`

There is `fontend_model` node set up to smth like that:
`<frontend_model>paypal/adminhtml_system_config_fieldset_expanded</frontend_model>`

And also check the implementation of PayPal fields:

`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Fieldset`

Comment: It can not create subgroups using the core magento?

Comment: You can't do this by simple manipulation of XML. It requires a bit of development like it is done in PayPal module.